# Costa Rica to Canada flight with hidden destinations (Salt lake city)

Tags: visas, canada, hidden-city-ticketing

We are planning a vacation to Costa Rica and looking at flight deals. We have found a good deal via Skiplagged for our return flight to Salt Lake City. The ticket is from Costa Rica to Victoria with a layover in Salt Lake City. Price works best for us.

But will they ask for a Canadian visa when we board the flight in Costa Rica? If yes, we cannot go for this option as we don't have Canadian visas. Please suggest.

Comment: What citizenship are you?

Comment: Do you normally need a Canada visa?

Comment: Watch for potential flight changes/cancellations. If the airline rebooks you on a different flight, you might end up in Canada on a direct. 'Hidden City' works, but don't expect the airline to be helpful if there is an issue.

Comment: @Aganju has it right.  This is a ticket from San Jose, Costa Rica to Victoria, British Columbia, Canada.  If there are issues, the airline can route you via Miami, Toronto, Vancouver, or anything it wants - it has no obligation to get you anywhere near Salt Lake City.

Comment: If you are American citizens, you're fine. Do you hold a different citizenship?

Comment: I don't understand your question about Canadian Visa. Your final destination is Canada and therefore you need to satisfy all entry requirements in Canada regardless of where you stop along the way.  You MAY need a US transit visa  in Salt Lake City. This depends on your citizenship(s).